JSON.parse() to class
I am experimenting with TypeScript in the playground and found that it allows me to assign the object returned by JSON.parse() to a class, even though the object won't have any methods, and this causes a runtime error. This is surprising to me as my understanding was that TypeScript is typesafe as long as you don't use as or any.
Is it possible to have the type system catch this case, using only type annotations, not changing the behaviour of the code?
class Foo {
    inner: Number;
    constructor(inner: Number) {
        this.inner = inner;
    }
    getInner() {
        return this.inner;
    }
}
let result: Foo = JSON.parse('{ "inner": 5 }');
console.log(result.getInner());


You are using any; that's what JSON.parse is typed to return.

Ah, that is unexpected. When I hover over result in the typescript playground it shows the type as Foo, but yes I can see that the signature for parse returns any and I guess it makes sense that once you have an any you can specify any type for it.

The type of result is Foo, you typed it explicitly. Then any is assignable to Foo (or anything else) so the compiler allows it.

As pointed out, you are using any... but furthermore "TypeScript is typesafe as long as you don't use as or any" is technically false. TS isn't meant to be fully type safe; there's often a tradeoff between type safety and usability, and TS sometimes favors usability.
